# mail function return address

Tags: php, email

I have like 50 different php files which all use the mail function. After all of this apparently the client doesn't want it to be from his default-ftp-user-login@godaddyshosting.com to be the default "from email address."

I've figured out that there is a "from" attribute which you can send with the mail function which can accomplish this, however if at all possible I don't really want to alter all these different pages. (Forgive me, I'm new to PHP and I know I should have put all these into one function so that I would only have to change that one, but live and learn I suppose!)

I've read that you can alter your php.ini file to change the default "from address" but I can't seem to find this file in the root directory! There isn't an etc dir either, but I know that it is a linux-based server and not windows.

Could I just upload a php.ini which changes the settings of the mail function only?

Any advice would be hugely appreciated, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ini setting is called `sendmail_from`. Run phpinfo() to check which directory contains the php.ini.